# Vim Function to Send Highlighted Text to a Git Commit

Tags: vimscript, git, functions

#### Problem:

Suppose I have the following text in my vim buffer:

```
This is a commit msg.
```

Suppose further I have a git repo located at `~/my_repo`.

**Goal:** Make a vim script so that I can highlight the text above, and have it sent as a git commit message within `~/my_repo`. It would look something like

```
:'<,'>Commit ~/my_repo
```

It would also have auto-complete on its repo argument.

#### Attempted Solution:

First, the autocomplete function (AFAIK I think this is OK?):

```
function! GitLocations()
  return find $HOME -name '.git' -printf '%h\n' "generates a list of all folders which contain a .git dir
endfunction
```

Next, the actual git commit function, which is incomplete:

```
function! CommitTextGitRepo(l1, l2, loc)
  let s:msg = ??? " how do I make this the highlighted text from line l1 to line l2?
  execute '!cd ' . a:loc . '&& git commit --allow-empty -m \"' . s:msg '\"'
endfunction
```

Assuming I can figure out how to get `CommitTextGitRepo()` working above, the final thing I would need is this (I think):

```
command! -nargs=* -complete=custom,GitLocations -range Commit call CommitToGitRepo(<line1>, <line2>, <q-args>)
```

I'm so close. How do I finish this up? :)

Comment: `GitLocations` won't work as expected, since you'll be calling Vim's `:find`, not the `find` command. Might try something like `return system('find $HOME ...')` (and add a `-type d` to it to skip submodules, perhaps?)

Comment: Good idea. With that, all I need is a way to bind `s:msg` to the contents of the line range (within `CommitTextGitRepo` above).

Comment: Maybe you could use `getline()` and `join()` like this: `let s:msg = join(getline(a:l1,a:l2), "\n")`

Comment: @saginaw: That approach worked to get s:msg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GitLocations` won't work as expected, since you'll be calling Vim's `:find`, not the `find` command. You might try something like:

```
return system('find $HOME -name ".git" -printf "%h\n"')
```

And you could add a `-type d` to it to skip submodules.

To get visually selected text, you can use [`getline()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getline%28%29):

```
let s:msg = join(getline("'<", "'>"), "\n") . "\n"
```

However, it will be easier if you took advantage of `git commit`'s ability to read the commit message from standard input. From [`man git commit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/git-commit.1.html):

```
-F <file>, --file=<file>
   Take the commit message from the given file. Use - to read the
   message from the standard input.
```

With [`w !`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Awrite_c), you can write a set of lines to the standard input of a shell command:

```
:[range]w[rite] [++opt] !{cmd}
                        Execute {cmd} with [range] lines as standard input
                        (note the space in front of the '!').  {cmd} is
                        executed like with ":!{cmd}", any '!' is replaced with
                        the previous command :!.
```

You could do something like:

```
function! CommitToGitRepo(l1, l2, loc) range
    exec a:l1 . ',' . a:l2 'w !cd' shellescape(a:loc) '; git commit --allow-empty -F -'
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 -range -complete=custom,GitLocations Commit call CommitToGitRepo(<line1>, <line2>, <args>)
```

Sources:

- [Call a vimscript function that has a range using local variables, from with in a vimscript function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8960966/2072269) on Stack Overflow

Comment: `-printf` isn't available in my OSX version of find but you can get something similar using internal Vim functions anyway: `return fnamemodify(finddir('.git', $HOME), ":h")`. I always work with my current directory inside the repo though so it's even easier since I don't need to get the git dir, I could just use `let l:rootdir = fnamemodify(finddir('.git', getcwd().';/'), ":h")` directly in the commit function (this uses upward as opposed to downward searching because of the semicolon).

Comment: @dash-tom-bang ah, well, if you're already in the required git repo, you can run `git commit` directly. :) Even so, the pure Vimscript way might be more efficient than calling `system('find ...')`, so that's something OP should look into. I assume OP is using GNU `find`, since they came up with that part themselves.